# using count and suppress/ignore group by

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to have `count` in the select clause with a `group by` which is suppressed in the count? I need the `count` to ignore the `group by` clause

I got this query which is counting the total entries. The query is generic generated and therefore I can't make any comprehensive changes like subqueries etc.

In some specific cases a group by is needed to retrieve the correct rows and because of this the group by can't be removed

```
SELECT count(dv.id) num
FROM `data_voucher` dv
LEFT JOIN `data_voucher_enclosure` de ON de.data_voucher_id=dv.id
WHERE IF(de.id IS NULL,0,1)=0
GROUP BY dv.id
```

Comment: I am not really sure what you mean. However, a `GROUP BY` *must* apply to all rows. If you want to apply the `GROUP BY` to only some rows, I think you have to resort to embedding the query in another query.

Comment: No I just need the count to ignore the group by

Comment: Do you want the count to return the total number of rows in the dataset (before grouping)? Can you add some sample input and desired results to your question?

Comment: @clarkk . . . Simply remove the `group by` or change the `group by` to be a value that is constant for all rows..  However, that doesn't sound like an option for you.

Answer (score 4):

> Is it possible to have `count` in the select clause with a `group by` which is suppressed in the `count`? I need the `count` to ignore the `group by` clause

well, the answer to your question is simply you can't have an aggregate that works on all the results, while having a group by statement. That's the whole purpose of the `group by` to create groups that change the behaviour of aggregates:

> The GROUP BY clause causes aggregations to occur in groups (naturally) for the columns you name.

cf [this blog post](http://database-programmer.blogspot.fr/2008/04/group-by-having-sum-avg-and-count.html) which is only the first result I found on google on this topic.

You'd need to redesign your query, the easiest way being to create a subquery, or a hell of a jointure. But without the schema and a little context on what you want this query to do, I can't give you an alternative that works.

I just can tell you that you're trying to use a hammer to tighten a screw...

Answer (score 0):

Have found an alternative where `COUNT DISTINCT` is used

```
SELECT count(distinct dv.id) num
FROM `data_voucher` dv
LEFT JOIN `data_voucher_enclosure` de ON de.data_voucher_id=dv.id
WHERE IF(de.id IS NULL,0,1)=0
```